# Min height for div when empty string

Tags: css, html

I would like to match the exact height in a div whether it comes with an empty string or not. Thought I had it but I realize that even I can set the min-height I'm loosing the padding when it's empt so there's a small offset.

Applying this doesn't seem to work

```
.docDetails .description {
    min-height: 1em;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why have you used `em` try `px` instead.

Comment: What's wrong with `em` in this case, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the min-height by padding.

You can calculate the px-to-em value by dividing 2px by your base font size. E. g. 2/16 = 0.125em. Don't forget to double that value.

```
.docDetails .description {
  min-height: 1.25em;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, well I haven't used px and actually I didn't do this before because in case in the future someone changes the base font size. I assumed 1em would take care of that but if I reckon like this it won't. If there's no way to refer something like 2/em I will definitely stick to this

Comment: Definitely it works, and actually that font has another size than the base one so it's always one along with the other. Thanks!

Comment: Something like what? Please study this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Btw, I've read I should use ex instead of em talking about heights. It works the same in my case though, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

you change the min height value is pixels.

> .docDetails .description {
>       min-height: 200px;
>       padding: 2px;
>       background:#003366;
>       }